# 415 Error Media Type (Cannot send JSON to Controller Spring MVC)

Tags: json, http, spring-mvc

I can't recieve json from client.
It shows 415 Error Media Type.

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "geolocation")
public class Geolocation implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private double lat;
    private double lon;

    public Geolocation(){}

    public Geolocation(double lat, double lon) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public Geolocation(int id, double lat, double lon) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
    }
    //  getters, setters
   }
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Geolocation test(@RequestBody Geolocation geolocation) {
    return geolocation;
}
```

json:

```
geolocation: {"id": 1,"lat":51.164861,"lon":71.451764}
```

I included jackson-core package, also added bean:

```
<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

**UPDATED**

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

request sent with chrome extension "advanced rest client"

Comment: which spring version, jackson version are you using? Could you show the HTTP request/response headers?

Comment: if the field names don't match it will return error 400 Bad Request, 415 means unsupported media type . post your client request? how did you make it? curl? js?

Comment: please, see updated information

Comment: As of Spring 4.1, Jackons 2.1+ is required (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#libraries ). In any case, you should not have both 1.9 and 2.5 versions on classpath.

Comment: Also, we're still missing the request/response HTTP headers...

Comment: Response: HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1091
Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 08:26:52 GMT

Comment: Request:    in headers i just added "Content-Type" : "application/json"

Comment: anyway, i need 3 dependecies, if i delete one of this, it shows 500 error